# Updating Google Spreadsheet cells from javascript client api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-gadget, google-api-js-client

i'm trying to update cells of a Google Spreadsheet using [cell feed changing content of a cell](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell).

I already used the Oauth 2.0 authentication and i have the oauth token.

The code i use (from a google gadget) to update a specific cell is:

```
var dataEntry='<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">\
            <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/xxxxxxx/od6/private/full/R2C2/</id>\
        <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"\
                href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/xxx/od6/private/full/R2C2/"/>\
        <gs:cell row="2" col="2" inputValue="prova"/>\
        </entry>';


        $.ajax({
                url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/xxxx/od6/private/full/R2C2/",
                type: "PUT",
                contentType: 'jsonp',
                processData: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: dataEntry,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }, success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                    alert("Succeeded");
                },
                beforeSend: setHeader
            });
```

The error that i receive is regarding the Access Control Allow Origin [image]

Dose anyone can tell me how i can solve this error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Noone have idea on how to update a spreadsheet using javascript? I solved the question using Oauth playground but i cannot solve this using javascript library. I used also the gapi.client.request but i receive an error like...PUT content.googleapis.com/https%3A//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/……d6/p‌​rivate/full/R2C2/?alt=json&key=xxxxxxxx 404 (Not Found) Any idea?

Comment: {"gapiRequest":{"data":{"body":"Not Found","headers":{"pragma":"no-cache","date":"Wed, 30 Oct 2013 15:27:48 GMT","content-encoding":"gzip","expires":"Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","server":"GSE","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","content-length":"29"},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}}}